# Emulator crashes and runs slowly on new computer

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

So I just bought myself a new machine and the emulator keeps on crashing or working really really weird while crashing. I had a laptop that ran the same emulator above fine and that laptop it nothing in compare to my new pc in terms of hardware,so I dont quite get it. I tried running it with different RAM / SD CARD / INTERNAL STORAGE settings,but none seem to work out.
Im on Windows 7 Ultimate running on 65bit.

Here is my last settings,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTyCx.png

And here is how my emulator actually looks like when running it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/022Ye.png

Comment: Have you installed HAXM? https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall and Install it again

Comment: Uninstall what? the AVD?

Answer (score 0):

Check if HAXM (driver and option in AVD) is enabled but the best solution (for me) is Genymotion.

https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/

Genymotion virtual devices are more faster than AVD, they use VirtualBox + Android x86 Image, performance are so good.

With this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952 you have full support for native library and you can install playstore etc.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the comment. I do have HAXM installed and Intel Virtualization enabled.
I will give Genymotion a chance once I would know I can't really do anything else to get the AVD running as it should,thank you mate.